# How do I express concentration of a substance at the interface between two membranes of different diffusivities and lengths at steady state?

Tags: physical-chemistry, diffusion

[image]

I am lost on this question from my textbook:

"A solute diffuses across two membranes, A and B. The membranes' thickness are $\Delta x_A$ and $\Delta x_B$ respectively. The membranes' diffusivities are $D_A$ and $D_B$ respectively. The concentration of the solute decreases linearly from $C_A$ at the left surface of A to $C_i$ at interface, then to $C_B$ at the right surface of B. Given a steady state diffusion process, derive an expression for $C_i$ in the terms of the other parameters of this system."

The answer sheet as provided in the textbook indicates that the correct solution is:
$$C_i = {{D_A C_A\over \Delta x_A}+{D_B C_B\over \Delta x_B}\over {D_A + D_B\over \Delta x_A + \Delta x_B}}$$

I tried to solve this by making the following equation:

$${C_A - C_i\over {\Delta x_A \over D_A}} = {C_i - C_B\over {\Delta x_B \over D_B}}$$

This was wrong because it can't be re-arranged into the correct equation as given by the textbook. My prof hinted that since the system is at steady state, the rate of diffusion through A is equal that of B. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The answer sheet as provided in the textbook indicates that the correct solution is:
> $$C_i = {{D_\text{A} C_\text{A}\over \Delta x_\text{A}}+{D_\text{B} C_\text{B}\over \Delta x_\text{B}}\over {D_\text{A} + D_\text{B}\over \Delta x_\text{A} + \Delta x_\text{B}}}$$

The textbook solution is wrong. Let test it by a trivial example, using numerical values $D_\text{A}=D_\text{B}=2$, $Δx_\text{A}=Δx_\text{B}=1$ for 2 identical membranes.

Then, $C_i= \frac{2C_\text{A} + 2 C_\text{B}}{2}=C_\text{A} + C_\text{B}$.

This is obviously wrong and the textbook provides a wrong equation.

---

Your initial equation for equal diffusion rates for the steady state is correct.

> $${C_\text{A} - C_i\over {\Delta x_\text{A} \over D_\text{A}}} = {C_i - C_\text{B}\over {\Delta x_\text{B} \over D_\text{B}}}$$

If we express $C_i = f(C_\text{A},C_\text{B})$:

$$C_\text{A}\frac{\Delta x_\text{B}}{D_\text{B}} - C_i\frac{\Delta x_\text{B}}{D_\text{B}} = C_i\frac{\Delta x_\text{A}}{ D_\text{A}} -  C_\text{B}\frac{\Delta x_\text{A}}{ D_\text{A}} $$

we get:

$$ C_i  =  \frac{C_\text{A}\frac{\Delta x_\text{B}}{D_\text{B}} +  C_\text{B}\frac{\Delta x_\text{A}}{ D_\text{A}}}{\frac{\Delta x_\text{A}}{ D_\text{A}} + \frac{\Delta x_\text{B}}{D_\text{B}}}   $$

This fits the general expectation the result should be in the form of a weighted average:

$$z = \frac{ax+by}{a+b}$$

Using our small test for identical membranes:

$$ C_i  =  \frac{C_\text{A}\frac{1}{2} +  C_\text{B}\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}}=\frac{C_\text{A} + C_\text{B}}{2}$$

what is obviously correct.

---

If we multiply the numerator and the denominator of the equation by   $\frac{D_\text{A}D_\text{B}}{\Delta x_\text{A}\Delta x_\text{B}}$, we get the alternative version of the equation. It is *almost* identical to the textbook solution, but it has the denominator the sum of the fractions and not the fraction of the sums.

$$ C_i  =  \frac{C_\text{A}\frac{D_\text{A}}{\Delta x_\text{A}} +  C_\text{B}\frac{ D_\text{B}}{\Delta x_\text{B}}}  {\frac{ D_\text{A}}{\Delta x_\text{A}} + \frac{D_\text{B}}{\Delta x_\text{B}}}   $$

Using our small test for identical membranes:

$$ C_i  =  \frac{2C_\text{A} +  2C_\text{B}}{2 + 2}=\frac{C_\text{A} + C_\text{B}}{2}$$

what is obviously correct.

Comment: Thanks! Just checked back with my groupmate in my module, my textbook is an older edition which has been rectified in newer ones.

Comment: The textbook equation would be correct, if they used in the denominator the sum of the fractions and not the fraction of the sums.